# monadic decomposition

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, monads

Let $\mathrm{F}: \mathcal{C} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{D} : \mathrm{G} $ be an adjunction with associated monad $\mathrm{T} =  \mathrm{G} \mathrm{F} .$

If $\mathcal{D} $ admits coequalizers of $\mathrm{G} $-split pairs, then the comparison functor $ \bar{\mathrm{G}}: \mathcal{D} \to  \mathrm{Alg}_{ \mathrm{T}} (\mathcal{C}) $ admits a left adjoint $ \bar{\mathrm{F}}.$

So we obtain an adjunction $ \bar{\mathrm{F}}: \bar{ \mathcal{C} }:= \mathrm{Alg}_{ \mathrm{T}} (\mathcal{C})  \rightleftarrows \mathcal{D} : \bar{\mathrm{G}} $ with associated monad $\bar{\mathrm{T}} =  \bar{\mathrm{G}} \bar{\mathrm{F}}.$

If $\mathcal{D} $ admits coequalizers of $\bar{\mathrm{G}} $-split pairs, then the comparison functor $ \mathcal{D} \to  \mathrm{Alg}_{ \bar{\mathrm{T}}} (\bar{ \mathcal{C} }) $ admits a left adjoint.

So if we assume that $\mathcal{D} $ admits coequalizers (in fact reflexive coequalizers are enough), we can iterate this process
starting with an adjunction $\mathrm{F_1}: \mathcal{C}_1 \rightleftarrows \mathcal{D} : \mathrm{G}_1 $ and get a sequence
$ (\mathrm{F_\mathrm{i}}: \mathcal{C}_\mathrm{i}\rightleftarrows \mathcal{D} : \mathrm{G}_\mathrm{i})_{ \mathrm{i} \geq 1 } $ of adjunctions, where 
$\mathrm{G}_\mathrm{i}: \mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}_\mathrm{i}:= \mathrm{Alg}_{ \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{i}-1}  } ( \mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{i}-1}   )   $ is the comparison functor for the adjunction
$ \mathrm{F_{\mathrm{i}-1}}: \mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{i}-1}\rightleftarrows \mathcal{D} : \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{i}-1} $ with associated monad $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{i}-1} $ if $\mathrm{i} > 1.$

Write $\mathcal{C}_{\infty}$ for the limit of the diagram $ ... \to \mathcal{C}_3 \to \mathcal{C}_2 \to \mathcal{C}_1$ so that we obtain a functor
$\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}_{\infty}$.

The functor $\mathcal{C}_{\infty} \to \mathcal{C}_1$ is right adjoint and conservative.

If $\mathcal{D}$ and all the categories $ \mathcal{C}_{\mathrm{i}} $ are presentable, all the right adjoint functors $ \mathrm{G}_{\mathrm{i}} $ preserve small limits and are accessible so that $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}_{\infty}$ preserves small limits and is accessible and so admits a left adjoint
by the adjoint functor theorem.

Does the functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}_{\infty}$ admit a left adjoint
without the presentability assumption on $\mathcal{D}?$

Denote $\mathrm{T}_\infty$ the monad associated to the adjunction $\mathcal{C}_{\infty} \rightleftarrows \mathcal{D}.$

It is tempting to believe that the monadic forgetful functor $\mathrm{Alg}_{\mathrm{T_\infty}} ( \mathcal{C}_\infty) \to  \mathcal{C}_\infty $ is an equivalence. This is equivalent to the condition that $\mathrm{T_\infty}$ is the identity monad or that the left adjoint of the functor 
$\mathcal{D} \to  \mathcal{C}_\infty  $ is fully faithul.
Is this true?

What can one say more about $\mathcal{C}_{\infty}$ and the functor $\mathcal{D} \to \mathcal{C}_{\infty}$?

Answer (score 8):

These questions were studied (in the dual case of comonads, née cotriples) by Applegate and Tierney in their 1970 paper [Iterated cotriples](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2FBFb0060440).

The answer to your first question is that yes, this functor always has an adjoint as long as $\mathcal{D}$ is cocomplete.  The adjoint can be constructed using a sequential colimit in $\mathcal{D}$ of the individual adjoints $\mathcal{C}_i\to \mathcal{D}$.

In general I expect that the adjoint $\mathcal{C}_\omega \to \mathcal{D}$ is not fully faithful, although A&T don't give a counterexample.  But they do show that the construction can be continued to all transfinite stages, and that if $\mathcal{D}$ is well-copowered then there is a sensible "$\Omega$-indexed limit"  of the tower (where $\Omega$ is the well-ordered proper class of ordinals) for which the analogous adjoint exists and is fully faithful.

**Edit:** This decomposition was studied further by Adamek-Herrlich-Tholen in [Monadic decompositions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022404989901291) and by MacDonald-Stone in [The tower and regular decomposition](http://www.numdam.org/item/CTGDC_1982__23_2_197_0).  I believe one or both of them may contain counterexamples to convergence at $\omega$.

Answer (score 1):

@MikeShulman’s answer gives the main references, but here is a quick counterexample to your specific question about whether the monad $T_\infty$ must be the identity.  Say a *widget* is a set $X$ equipped with $\mathbb{N}$-many partial operations $f_i : X \rightharpoonup X$, such that:

- each $f_i$ is an endomorphism of a subset $X_i \subseteq X$;
- $X_0$ is the whole of $X$;
- $X_{i+1}$ is precisely the set of fixpoints of $f_i$.

Say a widget is *special* if it satisfies the following axiom: if there is any element which is fixed by all $f_i$, then all elements of $X$ are equal.

Now widgets are finitary essentially-algebraic structures, and specialness is an infinitary essentially-algebraic condition; so there’s an evident notion of map between widgets — i.e. a map preserving the operations whenever they’re defined — and the categories of these structures and maps are very well-behaved.  Write $\newcommand{\W}{\mathbf{W}}\W$ for the category of widgets; $\W^\mathrm{sp}$ for the category of special widgets; and $\W_n$ for the category of objects like widgets, but with only the first $(n-1)$-many operations.

Resolving the adjunction of the forgetful functor $\W^\mathrm{sp} \to \newcommand{\Set}{\mathbf{Set}}\Set$, I claim we get exactly the tower of forgetful functors $\cdots \to \W_2 \to \W_1 \to \Set$; and the limit of this tower is just $\W$.  But now the monad of the forgetful functor $\W^\mathrm{sp} \to \W$ is not the identity — in fact, this adjunction is monadic.